# FORTH implementation for embedded SOCs

Tags: forth

I'm wondering if there is a good resource for FORTH implementations on recent SOCs.

I'm mostly interested in bare metal versions, something that can sit net to RTOS on an ESP32 or RISC-V for instance (so `gforth` might not be ideal).

And particularly, I'm looking at least at a version that can do networking (e.g. via WIFI, ideally via a source network stack implementation, which in RTOS might not be too hard)

Sadly, it seems pretty hard to tickle useful info out of Google – it mostly seems to think I can't spell fourth. Many results I do find seem outdated, and or seem very commercial; and it feels wrong to pay licensing fees for a network stack in the age of micropython.

This [Raspberry Pi JonesFORTH O/S](https://github.com/organix/pijFORTHos) looks pretty promising.

I wouldn't mind doing a bit of porting.

Answer (score 1):

Even if your question could be interpreted as opinion-based and might be looking for resources only, I am going to provide two links to living and active maintained projects which might fit your requirements.

> *I'm wondering if there is a good resource for FORTH implementations on recent SOCs. I'm mostly interested in bare metal versions*

You may have a look into

- [AmForth](https://amforth.sourceforge.net/)

  > *... for the Atmel AVR8 Atmega micro controller family and some variants of the TI MSP430. The RISC-V CPU (32bit) is currently beeing worked on.*

and

- [Mecrisp](https://mecrisp.sourceforge.net/), Stellaris

  > *an implementation of a standalone native code Forth for MSP430 microcontrollers*

  or Quintus

  > *a rewrite of classic Mecrisp-Stellaris with almost the same look-and-feel for RISC-V architecture, RV32I, RV32IM or RV32IMC flavour, and it includes support for MIPS M4K cores. FPGAs are conquered by using FemtoRV32 softcores.*

With both projects it is possible to achieve progress quite fast and easy depending what you try to achieve.

> *... can do networking (e.g. via WIFI, ideally via a source network stack implementation ... I wouldn't mind doing a bit of porting.*

For a more detailed answer and more guidance this part would need more information and some clearance.